# How to attach date in subject of mail using RDCOMClient

Tags: r, outlook, rdcomclient

I need to attach previous day date in subject of mail using RDCOMClient, tried below code but no luck.

```
d1=Sys.Date()-1

OutApp <- COMCreate("Outlook.Application")
outMail = OutApp$CreateItem(0)
outMail[["To"]] = paste("anc@xyb.com")

outMail[["subject"]] = "Database collection dated" + d1

outMail$Send()
```

error I received is

```
Error in "Database collection dated" + "d1" : 
  non-numeric argument to binary operator
```

Answer (score 1):

You maybe looking for `paste`/`paste0` to create a subject line.

```
outMail[["subject"]] = paste("Database collection dated",  d1)
```

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that you are trying to actually sum two Strings. You cannot do that in R. Unlike Python or JS, to concatenate two strings in R you should use the paste/paste0 functions.
Can you please try and use paste0?

```
outMail[["subject"]] <- paste0("Database collection dated ", d1)
```

Answer (score 1):

An option with `sprintf`

```
outMail[['subject']] <- sprintf('Database collected dated %s', d1)
```